# Parsing a List<List<String>> in Android?

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-api-java-client, adsense

I'm developing a custom Adsense report tool using [Google Java Client Library](http://code.google.com/apis/adsense/management/complete_guide.html#ret_rep-java) for **Android**. I've successfully authenticated and can make API calls to the server. but now when I receive the response, I don't know how to parse it and correctly show the result to user.

According to the javaDocs, [AdsenseReportsGenerateResponse.getRows()](http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/class_adsense_v1_schema_adsensereportsgenerateresponse.html#getRows) generates a List> But I'm kinda lost how to properly parse it to get:

```
-Today's earnings
-Yesterday's earnings
-Last 7 days
-Last month
-From the beginning of time
```

Here's part of my code related to the question

```
        Reports.Generate request = adsense.reports().generate(startDate, endDate);    

        request.setMetric(Arrays.asList("PAGE_VIEWS", "AD_REQUESTS", "AD_REQUESTS_COVERAGE", "CLICKS",
                "AD_REQUESTS_CTR", "COST_PER_CLICK", "AD_REQUESTS_RPM", "EARNINGS"));

        request.setDimension(Arrays.asList("DATE", "WEEK", "MONTH"));    
        request.setSort(Arrays.asList("+DATE"));

        AdsenseReportsGenerateResponse response = request.execute();

        //TODO: Here be dragons
        response.getRows();
```

Edit: Here is the javaDoc which mentions the [getRow()](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg-history/23952a1d2fef7ae22596fe2e920c12f704c301bb/apis/adsense/v1/com/google/api/services/adsense/model/AdsenseReportsGenerateResponse.html#getRows%28%29)

Hmm it seems nobody on this site can help?!

Comment: According to your link, `getRows()` returns `String[][]`.

Comment: Yes it's written String[][] but it actually returns List<List<String>>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find our sample code useful: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#AdSense_Management_API

Namely, this is the file you're interested in: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/adsense-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/adsense/cmdline/GenerateReport.java?repo=samples

Here's a snippet of code to print the output. Mind you, this is for a command line application, but should be easily adaptable:

```
if ((response.getRows() != null) && !response.getRows().isEmpty()) {
  // Display headers.
  for (AdsenseReportsGenerateResponseHeaders header : response.getHeaders()) {
    System.out.printf("%25s", header.getName());
  }
  System.out.println();

  // Display results.
  for (List<String> row : response.getRows()) {
    for (String column : row) {
      System.out.printf("%25s", column);
    }
    System.out.println();
    }

  System.out.println();
} else {
  System.out.println("No rows returned.");
}
```

As for getting the data for different periods of time, you should probably be running different reports, not cramming it all into one, as that would take different start dates and end dates. Here's how it works:

- Today's earnings: set the start and end dates to today, set the dimension list to just DATE
- Yesterday's earnings: set the start and end date to yesterday, set the dimension list to just DATE
- Last 7 days: if you want data per day, then you set the start date to 7 days ago, the end date to today, and the dimension list to just DATE. If you want to aggregate the stats, you may need to calculate this yourself, as WEEK and MONTH refer to a calendar week and month, not the last 7 days.
- Last month: start date 1st of last month, end date last day of the month, dimension MONTH.
- All time: how do you want this aggregated? Per month? Then set the start date to, say, 1980-1-1, end date to today and dimension to MONTH.

This blog post should help with understanding reporting concepts a bit better: http://adsenseapi.blogspot.com/2011/11/adsense-management-api-diving-into.html

Let me know if you need help with anything else!

Comment: Hi
I appreciate your detailed answer, I actually read all the above samples and blog posts before asking this question. but don't you think it's faster and more effective if we could wrap up all the reports into one instead of separate? considering it's a mobile device

Comment: You can put several things in the same report, yes, but at some point you're going to need different ones because of the interaction between report dates and aggregation (dimensions). How would you run a report that gets data for today (aggregated daily) and simultaneously gets all historical data for your account, aggregated monthly?

At most, you should be able to do one report per aggregation level, but anything beyond that would be difficult.

Comment: Ok
So lets say I want only the earnings of last 7 days in an array so I can show them in a listview to user, how can I get the data from the response? I mean, I want to separate the earnings from the dates (If I make a request with startdate=last7days, the response will include the dates as well)

Comment: You're always going to get the dimension in the report, otherwise you wouldn't be able to tell which value was which. Why don't you just loop through the returned array and incrementally populate the list view?

Comment: Because I just want to loop the earnings and display them in a listview **excluding** the dates, I hope you know what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

Its not a `List<List>` as far as I understand the api. Try this:

```
String[][] array = response.getRows();

for (int i = 0; i < array.getSize(); i++){

    String dimension = array[i][0];
    String metric = array[i][1];

    //Do what you want with them

}
```

I am writing this because the API says it has a list of dimensions with one value for the string and one for the metric, as far as I understand.

If you expect several cells on each row (Which I believe the API doesn't work that way), you need to add another for inside and get the size of the current list probably with something like `array[i].getSize()`

Post back if it doesn't help you.

Edit: I see now. Try this:

```
List list = response.getRows();

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){

List<String> list2 = list.get(i);

for (int j = 0; j < list2.size(); j++){
String value = list2.get(j);
//Do what you want
}

}
```

Comment: I've already tried that.
`Error: Type Mismatch: cannot convert from <List<List<String>> to String[][] `

Comment: See my edit. I think that you need to assume which property is on each position, however that doesnt seem right.

Comment: I tried and value is returning all the data in all columns/rows.
Example: 
`
request.setMetric(Arrays.asList("EARNINGS"));
request.setDimension(Arrays.asList("MONTH"));
.....
String value = list2.get(j);
Log.v(TAG, value);`
Output:
`
01-09 09:03:12.205: V/MyActivityValue(449): 2011-10
01-09 09:03:12.205: V/MyActivityValue(449): 36.92
01-09 09:03:12.205: V/MyActivityValue(449): 2011-11
01-09 09:03:12.205: V/MyActivityValue(449): 58.40
01-09 09:03:12.205: V/MyActivityValue(449): 2011-12
01-09 09:03:12.205: V/MyActivityValue(449): 52.87
01-09 09:03:12.205: V/MyActivityValue(449): 2012-01
`

Comment: I see. Well I am not sure how the API works. If its showing something maybe you are not setting the values correctly.